# Centos6 with cloud-init takes longer boot time

Tags: centos6, cloud-init, virt-install

Centos-6.6 vm image takes almost ten minutes of boot time when ran using `virsh`. I captured the logs using `virsh console`. It looks like this,

```
ci-info: +-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: | Route |  Destination  |    Gateway    |    Genmask    | Interface | Flags |
ci-info: +-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: |   0   | 192.168.122.0 |    0.0.0.0    | 255.255.255.0 |    eth0   |   U   |
ci-info: |   1   |    0.0.0.0    | 192.168.122.1 |    0.0.0.0    |    eth0   |   UG  |
ci-info: +-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-------+
2015-04-25 05:13:41,222 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id' failed [50/120s]: unexpected error ['Timeout' object has no attribute 'response']
2015-04-25 05:14:32,278 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id' failed [101/120s]: unexpected error ['Timeout' object has no attribute 'response']
2015-04-25 05:14:51,322 - DataSourceEc2.py[CRITICAL]: Giving up on md from ['http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id'] after 120 seconds
2015-04-25 05:14:51,990 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://192.168.122.1//latest/meta-data/instance-id' failed [0/120s]: bad status code [404]
2015-04-25 05:14:53,008 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://192.168.122.1//latest/meta-data/instance-id' failed [1/120s]: bad status code [404]
2015-04-25 05:14:54,022 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://192.168.122.1//latest/meta-data/instance-id' failed [2/120s]: bad status code [404]
```

My image tries to get some metadata from the remote server. Once that fails, it tries to collect the information from the local gateway.

Is this to do with `cloud-init`? Can i configure to turn off the remote server calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default cloud-init expects to receive metadata from an Amazon EC2-compatible metadata service, such as that included with OpenStack and possibly other services.

If you aren't running your VM under such a service, you have two options:

1. Disable or uninstall cloud-init. This is the easiest option and if you aren't running in a cloud service then you should do this. For example:

   ```
   systemctl mask cloud-init
   ```

   Or...
2. [Create a configuration drive](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/datasources.html#config-drive) as an ISO CD image containing the metadata which would have been obtained from the metadata service, if one had been present, and *permanently* attach the image to the virtual machine. You almost certainly do not need to do this.